# How to inverse the empirical function?

Tags: empirical-cumulative-distr-fn

I fitted a empirical distribution to a set of time series data (Y) by following code in R:

```
Ye=rank(Y)/(length(Y)+1)
```

How we can find the inverse of this distribution?
Thanks

Comment: 1) I'd have used the `ecdf` function. 2) The function doesn't have an actual inverse. What did you need it for? Random sampling?

Comment: @Glen_b Thank you This is what I did: I have a time series first I deseasonalized it then I differenced it to make it stationary then I fitted empirical distribution to fit copula (I want to use Markov process with copula) Finally I want to use inverse of the empirical distribution to be able to compare the results with original observations.If there is no inverse func I should probably do the comparing without transferring back

Comment: @glen_b An ECDF has right inverses but no left inverses; sometimes the former is good enough when an inverse is needed.  (A function $f$ has a right inverse $g$ when $f(g(y))=y$ for all $y$ in the image of $f$.)  The right inverse can be found with a binary search or its equivalent. I cannot tell from the information given so far whether a right inverse would be suitable in this situation.

Comment: Hmm, I missed the 'time series' part the first read through. If the time series isn't serially independent I'd be very unlikely to deal with the marginal distribution.

Comment: @whuber Yes, you're quite right (as usual) -- I was insufficiently precise. It would be nice to know what the actual thing the OP is trying to achieve (the only thing that jumps out at me is trying to sample from the empirical distribution, for which I'd just use `sample`)

Comment: To clarify my last sentence in the previous comment ... I'd use `sample` with `replace=TRUE` (of course).

Answer (score 1):

Basically answered in comments, recollected here:

> An ECDF has right inverses but no left inverses; sometimes the former is good enough when an inverse is needed. (A function  has a right inverse  when (())= for all  in the image of .) The right inverse can be found with a binary search or its equivalent. I cannot tell from the information given so far whether a right inverse would be suitable in this situation. –
> whuber